# Text above arrow from a node to a point

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to insert text along an arrow that represents an outflow of a compartment (node). I have included a minimum working example below.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{HTML}{B9DCFF}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=boxcolor, minimum size=1.5em, text width = 2cm, align = center, minimum height = 2cm]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[->, red, text = black]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex']
    \node [block] (S) {$S$};

    \draw [arrow] (S.east) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to insert some text in the highlighted region in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{HTML}{B9DCFF}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=boxcolor, minimum size=1.5em, text width = 2cm, align = center, minimum height = 2cm]
    \tikzstyle{arrow}=[->, red, text = black]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex']
        \node [block] (S) {$S$};
        
        \draw [arrow] (S.east) -- node [above] {Text} (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]